# how to make an unclickable/disabled/grey list item in yii

Tags: php, yii

Inside  layout>main.php i have this

```
    array('label'=>'Appointment',

     'items'=>array(array('label'=>'Appointment(Office)','url'=>array('/appointOffice')),

      array('label'=>'Appointment(User)','url'=>array('/appointUser')))),
```

I want to make one of the items unclickable for a specific type of users. example: office users cant click Appointment(User). Can anyone explain a bit how to disable an item? I am using MbMenu extension. Just to mention, i don't want to hide the item, i want make it disable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the record, here's the corrected answer;
You need to have some logic in place to decide whether to display a link or not.

```
array('label'=>'Appointment',

     'items'=>array(array('label'=>'Appointment(Office)','url'=>array('/appointOffice')),

      array('label'=>'Appointment(User)','url'=>!User->isOfficeUser() ? array('/appointUser') : ''))),
```

Answer (score -1):

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CMenu#items-detail

linkOptions: array, optional, additional HTML attributes to be rendered for the link or span tag of the menu item.
itemOptions: array, optional, additional HTML attributes to be rendered for the container tag of the menu item.

So, `'linkOptions' => array('disabled' => Yii::user()->group == 'groupForDisabledLink')`.

// upd

BTW, better use routes rather than direct url, via `'url' => array('controller/action')`.

Comment: Be careful of using this disabled function, it doesn't work in many browsers. Just tested it in Chrome and Firefox on a Linux machine and it doesn't work in either of them. You'd be better including some logic to decide whether or not to have a url for the link, e.g. 'url' => User->isAdmin ? array('/appointUser') : ''

Comment: @JoeMiller what? it is HTML attribute 'disabled' which applied to tag "a". It works even in IE 6.

Comment: No, it's not. See here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link It says;Note: While there is no disabled attribute in the HTML standard, there is a disabled attribute on the HTMLLinkElement DOM object.

The use of disabled as an HTML attribute is non-standard and only used by some browsers. Do not use it. To achieve a similar effect, use one of the following techniques:

If the disabled attribute has been added directly to the element on the page, do not include the <link> element instead;
Set the disabled property of the StyleSheet DOM object via scripting.

Comment: ow...that's unexpected. But the other way will work for me also i guess. Ty for the info.